# regex needs to find digit contains only [st||nd||rd||th]

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex to find only digit which contains these words:

```
 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.
```

from the following text:

```
 <xps:span class="ref_sn">Huang</xps:span></xps:span> <xps:span
 class="ref_au"><xps:span class="ref_gn">K.</xps:span> <xps:span
 class="ref_sn">Chingin</xps:span></xps:span> <xps:span
 class="ref_au"><xps:span class="ref_gn">R.</xps:span> <xps:span
 class="ref_sn">Zenobi</xps:span> 1st</xps:span> <xps:span
 class="ref_atitle">Real<span class='xps_ndash'>&#8211;iou</span>time,
 on<span class='xps_ndash'> 2nd &#8211;iou</span>line 4th monitoring of
 organic chemical reactions using 3rd extractive electrospray
 ionization tandem mass 5th spectrometry</xps:span> <xps:span
 class="ref_jtitle">Rapid Commun. Mass Spectrom.</xps:span>
```

From which I need to convert those alphabets to sup.

I am using this regex but it's not working.

```
(\b)(\d+([st|nd|rd|th]+)\b)
```

Answer (score 5):

`[st|nd|rd|th]` is [**Character class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) also called **character set**, you can tell the regex engine to match only one out of several characters.

```
[st|nd|rd|th]            any character of: 
                       's', 't', '|', 'n', 'd',
                       '|', 'r', 'd', '|', 't', 'h'
```

You need to use `(...)` instead of `[...]`

---

You can try

```
\d+(?=st|nd|rd|th)
```

Here is [demo](http://regex101.com/r/sI2mX7/1)

Sample code:

```
String str = "1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+(?=st|nd|rd|th)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

*Output*:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

---

You can modify your regex as shown below using capturing groups and get the desired matched group:

```
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("(\\d+)(st|nd|rd|th)");
Matcher m=p.matcher(str);
while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try with:

Just try with following regex:

```
(\d+(?:st|nd|rd|th))
```

[demo](http://regex101.com/r/gR5kX9/1)

Answer (score 0):

Just modifying your code a bit :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "Huang K. Chingin R. Zenobi 1st Real–ioutime, on 2nd –iouline 4th monitoring of organic chemical reactions using 3rd extractive electrospray ionization tandem mass 5th spectrometry Rapid Commun. Mass Spectrom";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+(?=st|nd|rd|th)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
}
```

O/P :

```
1
2
4
3
5
```

Comment: I need a regex to find only digit.

Answer (score 0):

To extract only the numbers before st, nd, rd, th use:

```
\d+(?=st|nd|rd|th)
```

---

If you want the regex to be case insensitive use:

```
(?i)\d+(?=st|nd|rd|th)
```